# Load Earlier With smooth scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, smooth-scrolling

I am working on chat application. In my app load earlier message feature implemented which is not smooth and accurate like `whatsapp`.

I am using `UITableview` for chat listing and fetching more data using

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 &&  scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 50{
        print(" scrollViewDidScroll Load Earlier start- \(Utils.stringFromNSDate(Date(), inMillisec: true, useUTC: true)!)")
         if !self.messageFetcher.isHideLoadMoreDisplay{
            if self.messageFetcher.arrayOfallChatMessagesData.count > 0 && !isCheckLoading{
                self.isCheckLoading = true
                let message = self.messageFetcher.arrayOfallChatMessagesData[0]
                self.messageIdForMessageDisplay =  (message.chatMessageId )
                self.loadMoreDataLoad(threadId: self.messageFetcher.chatThreadId, isloadFromServer: false)
            }
        }
         print(" scrollViewDidScroll Load Earlier end- \(Utils.stringFromNSDate(Date(), inMillisec: true, useUTC: true)!)")
    }
}
```

So, Which is better way to achieve load earlier with smoothness same as like whatspp Application.

Comment: loadMoreDataLoad will call Webservice ? to fetch data

Comment: Fetching Form Local DataBase..

Comment: You should load data it in `cellForRow`  in the case of paging Please  show `loadMoreDataLoad` method

Comment: i tried so many option but after fetching and reload table  scrolling stop and position disturb

Comment: @BalKrishan Yadav , Have you found any solution yet? I also need this. Please share if you have implemented this.

Answer (score -1):

You should always load your data in CellForWowatIndexpath method, and also use pagination and load more data when that last cell is displayed. You can call load more method on cellWillDisplay method. And last but not least if you are loading images use SDWebimage to load the image so that the scrolling becomes smooth

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // load dats here



    return cell
}
```

Reload the data when last cell is visible

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastItem = self.YourArray.count - 1

        if indexPath.row == lastItem
        {
            //call load more data method
        }

    else{
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing.. But I want implementation from top Like Whatsapp App..